# nth: child / of-type does not seem to work on my site

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I thought I has this nth-child or nth-of-type stuff down, but somehow it does not seem to work on my site. I have http://www.dateworld.co.za/ and need the 3rd tab to be a red background, but somehow this code does not seem to work...

Can anybody help me?

```
 div#headernav ul li a {
 padding: 0px 16px;
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font: bold 12px/30px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right:6px;
 background-color:#2274D9;
 }

 div#headernav ul li a:nth-of-type(3){
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 }
```

Thanks and regards 
Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your html structure, but does your css need to be something like this?

```
div#headernav ul li:nth-of-type(3) a{
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly, thank so much for your help, would never have guessed the a comes after ;-)

Comment: Okay, so once I sign up and log in, that Join Now tab disappears, but the 3rd list item still highlights red, how do I remove that and make it the same colour as the other tabs?

Comment: I'd probably just add a class to the join now tab. and then target that with the css rather than nth-of-type

Comment: Ive tried this but it does not highlight the Tab, it highlights the margin to the right of the tab

Comment: Okay, I know its not aideal, but ive added a list item and set it to display none, it now works as expected, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this selector instead:

```
div#headernav ul li:nth-of-type(3) a
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TJ6Lc/

Also, you don't need `nth-of-type`, you can just use `nth-child`:

```
div#headernav ul li:nth-child(3) a
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TJ6Lc/1/

---

The selector you were using:

```
div#headernav ul li a:nth-of-type(3)
```

was looking for the third `a` element inside an `li` element, which does not correspond with what you're actually trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying your styles to the `li`, not the `a`, as the `li` elements contain only *one* `a`, but the `ul` contains many `li`s:

```
div#headernav ul li:nth-child(3){
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 }
```

Comment: The styles should go to the `a`, it's just `:nth-of-type()` not being used correctly.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your quick response, Ive done that, I think in normal circumstances it wouldve worked, but it doesnt work this time, please see what it looks like now?